# how to access instances & variables within an if else statement

Tags: java

how do I access variable '`user_input`' & instance '`c1`'? From what I understand, they are inaccessible while out of the scope of the `if-else` statement @ choice 1.

Please see the following:

```
 public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int choice;
    int user_input;

    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    do
    {
        System.out.println ("==== Circle Computation =========");
        System.out.println ("| 1. Create a new circle\t|");
        System.out.println ("| 2. Print area\t\t\t|");
        System.out.println ("| 3. Print circumference\t|");
        System.out.println ("| 4. Quit\t\t\t|");

        System.out.println ("Choose option (1 - 3): ");
        choice = in.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter the radius to compute the area & circumference:");
            user_input = in.nextInt();              

            Circle c1 = new Circle(user_input);     //refer to prob @ choice '2'
            System.out.println ("A new circle is created.\n");
        }

        if (choice == 2)
        {           
            //Prob - instance 'c1' & var 'user_input' @ choice '1' not visible in other if-else statements?
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685023/creating-an-instance-of-an-object-within-an-if-in-c-sharp
            System.out.println ("Area of circle:");
            System.out.println ("Radius: " + c1.getRadius());
            System.out.println ("Area: " + c1.area());
        }
```

Comment: They are declared at main's scope, so they're accessible from within main's scope and any scope inside.

Comment: `user_input` is accessible. About c1 - declare it in the same place where you declared `user_input` and it'll be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `user_input` is accessible in both the if conditions cause their scope is `main` method

In the statement

```
if (choice == 1)
{
    System.out.println ("Enter the radius to compute the area & circumference:");
    user_input = in.nextInt();              

    Circle c1 = new Circle(user_input);     //refer to prob @ choice '2'
    System.out.println ("A new circle is created.\n");
}
```

The scope of `c1` is the braces inclosing if condition . If you want it to accessible in the other if loop then you might want to move `c1` out like below. I have changed the scope of `c1` to `main` method so that it adheres to your logic.

```
    Circle c1 = null;
    do
    {
        System.out.println ("==== Circle Computation =========");
        System.out.println ("| 1. Create a new circle\t|");
        System.out.println ("| 2. Print area\t\t\t|");
        System.out.println ("| 3. Print circumference\t|");
        System.out.println ("| 4. Quit\t\t\t|");

        System.out.println ("Choose option (1 - 3): ");
        choice = in.nextInt();
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            System.out.println ("Enter the radius to compute the area & circumference:");
            user_input = in.nextInt();              

            c1 = new Circle(user_input);     //refer to prob @ choice '2'
            System.out.println ("A new circle is created.\n");
        }

        if (choice == 2)
        {           
            //Prob - instance 'c1' & var 'user_input' @ choice '1' not visible in other if-else statements?
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685023/creating-an-instance-of-an-object-within-an-if-in-c-sharp
            System.out.println ("Area of circle:");
            System.out.println ("Radius: " + c1.getRadius());
            System.out.println ("Area: " + c1.area());
        }           
    }
```

Comment: An `if` doesn't constitute a *loop*. And there is no else. And if there was, the else block wouldn't be able to access c1. Moreove, given the logic of the program, the OP doesn't want to reinitialize the circle to null at each iteration.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet Yes, looking at the logic I think its better to change the scope of c1 to main method. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: prob is the user wants to access choice 1 1st, then get to choice 2?

Comment: @brainsfrying this works.. `Circle` object created in the first loop remains during the subsequent runs, until a new `Circle` object gets created

Answer (score 2):

`Circle c1` is defined in the `if` statement and therefore can be access only there.

`user_input` is defined outside the while loop and therefor can be access throughout the loop

Every variable has it's [definition scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29). When a variable in c defined in a block (meaning between a `{` and a `}`) it is limited to that scope, meaning it can be referenced only in that scope.

Answer (score 0):

**user_input** variable created into main method block
so it can be accessable where if or else block  .
but **C1**  can not be accessable beause it is local variable/instance into IF block

Answer (score -2):

User_input can be used throughout the method.

C1 can't be used in second if portion

Comment: Err, no. `c1` is declared inside the if block, so it can only be used from inside this if block.

Comment: only user_input, c1 is declared within the if statement

Comment: And it's still completely wrong. Your two sentences contradict themselves, and the second one is still wrong.